# Bootstrap Table Overflow

Tags: html, css, html-table, overflow, bootstrap-4

I have two tables side by side. I have the bootstrap grid system in place and am able to get the tables to be dynamic and look all pretty. My issue is when I dynamically add a a lengthy string, the overflow of text in the table pushes the table over into the second table. So it's not very responsive. It seems to works great when I do not exceed a certain character count.  Is this a rule of the bootstrap table grid?

[image: Overlapped Table]

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h2 class="sub-header">TITLE</h2>
      <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped ">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="col-md-1">Subject</th>
                  <th class="col-md-2">Comments</th>
                  <th class="col-md-3">Owner</th>
                  <th class="col-md-3">Really Long Header that will case the table to overflow</th>
                  <th class="col-md-3">Date Activity Logged</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-4">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-5">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-4">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-5">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-4">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-5">1,001111111111111111111111111111</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h2 class="sub-header">Title Two For Table Two</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="col-md-1">#</th>
                  <th class="col-md-2">Header</th>
                  <th class="col-md-3">Header</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
    </div>
    </div>    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that the `td's` have a column size. Once I removed the `"col-md-2"` from the `td` in the table the bootstrap was responsive.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h2 class="sub-header">TITLE</h2>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped ">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
            <th>Owner</th>
            <th>Really Long Header</th>
            <th>Date Activity Logged</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h2 class="sub-header">Title Two For Table Two</h2>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Comment</th>
            <th>Created By</th>
            <th>Case/Merchant Number</th>
            <th>Created Time</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>1,001</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```