# Bootstrap table overflows screen and navbar doesn't

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So this is a bit of a compound question. Please keep in mind that I'm not a professional webdev. Also I did try the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819911/bootstrap-table-overflow) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553675/bootstrap-table-overflow)

The picture is a mockup of how it looks on mobile. On desktop everything looks fine. It isn't until I open it up on mobile that there's any issues.

Ideally I'd like the table to fit on the screen with a scrollbar but it's also bothersome that the nav bar doesn't extend the same width as the table.

[image]

I've tried to boil the code down to just elements, classes and styles. Please let me know if there's anything else you'd like to see

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- ✅ load jQuery ✅ -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="banner_element"></div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" style="margin-top: 10px;">             
        <button class="navbar-toggler" 
                type="button" 
                data-toggle="collapse" 
                data-target="#navbarDiv" 
                aria-controls="navbarDiv" 
                aria-expanded="false" 
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarDiv">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">Click me</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-bottom: 100px;">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <h1 class="mb-3">Page Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-bottom: 100px;">
            <table class="table" style="overflow-x: visible; overflow-y: visible; height: 100%;" id="myTable">
                <thead>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>4</th>
                    <th>5</th>
                </thead>
                <tr id='${element["Id"]}'>
                  <td><button onclick="location.href='/'"></button></td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>4</td>
                  <td>5</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from Bootstrap 4, they have covered this (added responsiveness).

**You can either make table responsive with being breakpoint specific:**

Using `.table-responsive{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}` as needed to create responsive tables up to a particular breakpoint. *From that breakpoint and up, the table will behave normally and not scroll horizontally.*

And by making table always (on all screen widths) responsive (scrollbar), by adding `.table-responsive` class on table.

For something more advanced (making) columns go into new row and similar, you can refer to this [responsive data tables](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/)

Comment: that link you posted is awesome

Comment: I just rolled the css in from that link at it worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: Glad that it helps. :) 
There are actually many resources that are using styles on "generalized" elements -> by generalized I mean html elements which are used (without using classes) and are actually applied independently if you are using `<table>` `tr` `td`

By searching for "Responsive data tables", you will be able to find more